# How do I shorten this code with python list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to code this,

```
def retrieve_smallest_letter(words):
"""
Input: 'words' (lst) which represents a list of strings.
Output: A new list with the smaller letter of the each word's 
          first and last index value compared to be appended to the list.
For Example:
>>> lst = ['sandbox', 'portabello', 'lion', 'australia', 'salamander']
>>> retrieve_smallest_letter(lst)
['s', 'o', 'l', 'a', 'r']
"""
```

**My code**

```
def retrieve_smallest_letter(words):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(words)):
        first_word = words[i][0]
        last_word = words[i][len(words[i])-1]
        if first_word < last_word:
            lst.append(str(first_word))
        else:
            lst.append(str(last_word))

    return lst
```

How can I shorten this code with list comprehension?

Comment: what is the definition of smallest letter?

Comment: shorter does not necessarily mean better. Whilst this could possibly be reduced to a 'clever' on-liner using list-comprehension, it would be hard to understand. I'd replace `for i in range(len(words))` with `for i in words` though. Better, `for word in words`

Comment: @SiHa list comprehensions are optimized to run faster, and provide powerful concise syntax that makes developing code faster. Being different from traditional C if, for, while structures does not mean it is "hard to understand". The list comprehension for this problem is relatively simple compare to what you can do.

Comment: @Andrew-Harelson I'm well aware of that, thanks. In my opinion, a listcomp is still the wrong choice here, especially considering that OP doesn't know them well enough to construct it. It is of course, just my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to understand is that a list comprehension is fundamentally restricted semantics on a for loop:

```py
r = [a for a in b if c]
```

is essentially syntactic sugar for

```py
r = []
for a in b:
    if c:
        r.append(a)
```

so the first step is to get the problem into a "shape" which fits a list comprehension:

- simple iteration and filtering
- no assignments (because that's as yet not supported)
- only one production

Using Python correctly also help, do let's start by simplifying the existing loop:

- iterate collections directly, Python has a powerful iterator protocol and you don't usually iterate by indexing unless absolutely necessary
- use indexing or destructuring on the word, Python allows indexing from the end (using negative indices)
- perform the selection "inline" as a single expression, using either a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) or in this case [the `min` builtin which does exactly what's needed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

```py
def retrieve_smallest_letter(words):
    lst = []
    for word in words:
        lst.append(min(word[0], word[-1]))

    return lst
```

or

```py
def retrieve_smallest_letter(words):
    lst = []
    for first, *_, last in words:
        lst.append(min(first, last))

    return lst
```

from there, the conversion is trivial (there is no filtering so it can be ignored):

```py
def retrieve_smallest_letter(words):
    return [min(first, last) for first, *_, last in words]
```

Comment: This is a really cool post for teaching. Thank you for this!

Comment: @Masklinn, thanks so much for this, your explanation is very clear. But I got one more question, what does *_ do? I've never seen this before.

Comment: @BryanHii that's [extended iterable unpacking (PEP 3132)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), it's the extension of regular unpacking e.g. `for a, b in c`, but allows for "catch all" values at the start / end / middle of the capture. The `_` is used so linters / editors don't warn about an unused variable, since we don't need the middle bits. So here it captures the first and last letters, and captures but ignores the ones in the middle. It could be written as `for first, *_middle, last in ...` if you prefer (again the `_` prefix is to signal to editor that the variable is ignored).

Comment: This solution will fail on strings with one character because it can't unpack it into `first` and `last`. The indexing method covers those cases too as the first (0) and last (-1) indices all point to the same character.

Comment: *no assignments (because that's as yet not supported)*, actually [it is since python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

Comment: @mozway that's a bit of a different context, you can assign in expressions but some languages provide for singular assignments in listcomps (you can emulate that in python with `for val in [expr]` but it's ugly). In fact [assignment in listcomps were one of the options in 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#special-casing-comprehensions).

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```py
[min(word[0], word[-1]) for word in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [min(w[0], w[-1]) for w in words]
```